# SSRS 2008 display row even if details are null

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report with a row group and details. There are several columns of data displayed for the group and the details. If there are no details for a row group, the whole row disappears from the report. I want the row group columns to display regardless. How do I do this?

Comment: I would handle this by guaranteeing in your SQL return that you return a row for every row group no matter what.  On the row groups that are effectively empty just do not show any data in that row... so in your SQL the data would likely be null for all columns

Comment: I believe I am already doing that. If I run the query in SQL, it returns rows for groups that don't show in the report. I assume the SSRS has some auto-hide or collapse thing it's doing.

Comment: Oh, I would check the sorting in the group and in the details and make sure you are sorting by what you are grouping on first.  That is usually what trips me up here.

Comment: There is no group without details. If the dataset is empty, what should be the grouping value?

Comment: best thing would be to do a cross join to a derived table that has all the distinct group values and return blank for details.. this ensures that the groups are present in the report.. regardless of the detail data..